# jackson reading in non-existent and null values to “” and marshalling out “” to non-existent values?

Tags: json, jackson

I read through this post [Jackson: deserializing null Strings as empty Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654810/jackson-deserializing-null-strings-as-empty-strings) which has this cool trick

```
mapper.configOverride(String.class)
  .setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
```

THEN on the flipside, I read through this post [Jackson serialization: ignore empty values (or null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089651/jackson-serialization-ignore-empty-values-or-null) which has this cool trick

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
```

This is VERY VERY close except I really don't want incoming data to be null in any case.  I have the following code printing 4 situations with the above settings BUT want to fix the null piece so any json we unmarshal into java results in

```
public class MapperTest {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MapperTest.class);

    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public MapperTest() {
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configOverride(String.class)
                .setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        new MapperTest().start();
    }

    private void start() throws JsonProcessingException {
        //write out java color=null resulting in NO field...
        String val = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Something());
        log.info("val="+val);

        Something something = mapper.readValue(val, Something.class);
        log.info("value='"+something.getColor()+"'");

        //write out java color="" resulting in NO field...
        Something s = new Something();
        s.setColor("");
        String val2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Something());
        log.info("val="+val2);

        String temp = "{\"color\":null,\"something\":0}";
        Something something2 = mapper.readValue(temp, Something.class);
        log.info("value2='"+something2.getColor()+"'");
    }
}
```

The output is then

```
    INFO: val={"something":0}
    INFO: value='null'
    INFO: val={"something":0}
    INFO: value2=''
```

NOTE: The value = 'null' is NOT what I desire and want that to also be empty string.  Notice that if customers give a color:'null', it does result in empty string.  Non-existence should result in the same thing for us "".
This is a HUGE win in less mistakes in this area 'for us' I mean.
thanks,
Dean